# How to access properties of the object type c#?

Tags: c#, list, object, anonymous-types

```
var obj1 = new A()
{
  Name = "abc",
  Id = 1
}

var obj2 = new B()
{
   Place = "XYZ",
   Pincode = 123456
}
var obj3 = new C()
{
   Mark = 100,
   Standard = "Tenth"
}

var myList = new List<object>();
myList .add(obj1);
myList .add(obj2);
myList .add(obj3);
```

This is my code structure. I need to access the properties of the `myList` object. i.e) I need to access the properties like `Name`, `Id`, `Place`, `Pincode`, `Mark`, `Standard` from the `myList` object and it's corresponding values.

How to achieve it?

Comment: You can use **Reflection** and  call [`GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype) + [`GetProperties()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties) on each element of `myList`

Comment: Check the type of the item and cast (or use pattern matching)

Comment: How do you want to access properties? `obj1.Place` doesn't make sense, so what is the usage?

Comment: Usually, keeping a collection of different types means you have a design problem. What's your reasoning for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below. Working code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LslR6u)

```
public static List<List<string>> GetProperties(List<object> myList) 
{
    //  If you don't want two lists, you can use Dictionary<key, value>
    List<string> props = new List<string>();
    List<string> values = new List<string>();

    foreach (var a in myList)
    {
        if(a == null)
            continue;

        var propsInfo = a.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in propsInfo)
        {
            if(!props.Contains(prop.Name))
            {
                props.Add(prop.Name);
                values.Add(prop.GetValue(a, null).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return new List<List<string>> { props, values};
}
```

Comment: I need to access properties and it's corresponding values.

Comment: I don't understand why you need both properties and values?

Comment: updated the logic and the working code link, please refer

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, usually keeping completely different types in the same collection is wrong. However, that doesn't mean that's always the case, and so assuming you have a good enough reason to do that - here's one option to do it.
Assuming c# 7 or higher, your best option would probably be to (ab)use [switch with pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements):

```
foreach(var obj in myList)
{
    switch(obj)
    {
        case A a:
            DoSomethingWithA(a);
            break;
        case B b:
            DoSomethingWithB(b);
            break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use to compare two objects.  I don't know if this is your scenario but I hope it helps you get what you need it for.

```
protected List<string> GetProperties(List<object> myList) 
{
    List<string> props = new List<string>();
    
    foreach (var a in myList)
    {
       if(a == null)
         continue;
        
       var propsInfo = a.GetType().GetProperties();
       foreach (var prop in propsInfo)
       {
          if(!props.Contains(prop.Name))
          {
             props.Add(prop.Name);
          }
       }
    }
    return props;
}
```

Comment: The question is not about checking equality.

Comment: Was this related to any other question?

Comment: I got you, You have used the logic to get the Properties here and asking the user to use the same logic, Am I right?

Comment: I thought the user was looking for properties of the object not property values.  I just posted the loop to show how and why I used it because.  I think I misunderstood the question.  The piece of code is a little irregular.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to get values out of an object (property values), that is a different story.

```
foreach (objectType obj in mylist)
{
    someVariable1 = obj.name;
    someVariable2 = obj.Id;
}
```